# Filename is changing when uploading files

Tags: php, mysqli

I created a page that can upload files to database. However, whenever a filename has a special characters on it, it changes it names in the database. For example, I have a pdf file named Biñan.pdf it changes to BIÃ‘AÃ‘.pdf

Here is my function that will upload files.

```
<?php

function upload_image()
{
    if ( isset($_FILES["user_image"]) )
    {
        $destination = './upload/' . $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        return $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
    }
}

function get_image_name($user_id)
{
    include('db3.php');
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT image FROM users10 WHERE id = '$user_id'");
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        return $row["image"];
    }
}

function get_total_all_records()
{
    include('db3.php');
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users10");
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    return $statement->rowCount();
}

?>
```

Comment: Change your table type to utf8

Comment: you still have SQL injection in your function get_image_name()

Comment: why do you prepare your statement as long as you will not parameterize your query?

Comment: You did not include the code that saves the file information to database

Answer (score 0):

Save a dump **backup** and try to change charsets for database, table and field to **UTF-8**

For a database

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

For a table

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

For a columns ( be careful about field type keywords )

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <column_name> VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Tried changing it to utf8 and nothing happens

Comment: Change your file encoding to UTF-8 and use this row over all your code. 

**header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');**

Comment: You mean html not plain? Ive been trying that for hours and still doesnt work. The result is still the same, the file name is changing

Comment: ok update the filename in my sql is now Biñan.pdf but when i check my upload folder it is not changing?